# nginx infinite keepalive_requests

Tags: nginx, timeout, keep-alive

We continually poll our nginx server every 5 seconds, using keep-alive to hold the connection open.

By default keepalive_requests is set to 100, so after 100 requests on the keep-alive connection, nginx disconnects.

Currently we have set keepalive_requests to a very large number to solve this problem, however is there a way to make it infinite?

We want to hold the connection open indefinitely, regardless of how many requests are made on the same keep-alive connection. keepalive_timeout is enough for us.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/425065/55544

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only way to do this is to modify the source.  This is the relevant code [within nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L1471-L1478):

```
if (r->keepalive) {
    if (clcf->keepalive_timeout == 0) {
        r->keepalive = 0;

    } else if (r->connection->requests >= clcf->keepalive_requests) {
        r->keepalive = 0;
    } else {...}
```

A value of 4294967295 for `keepalive_requests` corresponds to about 680 years of 5-second requests.  If you need more than that, I'd recommend patching the code.